# A good way to check a chars 'integrity'

Tags: c#

I'm working on making my own password generator; and I want it to create passwords that contain numbers, lowercase-letters, and uppercase-letters.

I am writing the program in C#, using Visual Studio.
Say I use the code below:

```
Random Rand = new Random();

Char C = Convert.ToChar(Rand.Next(0x30, 0x5A));
```

How could I make my program check whether (C) is equal to a number or a uppercase-letter?

Comment: see my answer below for a better solution to generating a random string from a given alphabet.

Comment: You probably should not use `Random` for this.  Use a `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` instead such as [`System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better (and standard) way, is to create an 'alphabet' string of allowable characters and then generate a random index into the string, to select an allowable character.

Much better than first generating a random character and *then* checking if it is allowable.

```
"0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

**Note** the removed lowercase 'l' (looks like 1). You should remove any others such as zero versus 'O' possibly...or whatever your password rules allow)

Here's an example of using this technique to generate random strings:

```
public static class RandomUtils
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public static string GenerateRandomAlphaNumericString(int length)
    {
        const string alpha = 
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        return GenerateRandomString(length, alpha);
    }

    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length, string alphabet)
    {
        int maxlen = alphabet.Length;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(alphabet[random.Next(0, maxlen)]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not looking into your answer sooner, after trying a different way I can see the complications.. If you could please show me an example, I will consider changing the answer to yours.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) (for decimal digits), or [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx) and [`Char.IsUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s91f3by.aspx).

These are all static methods defined on the [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) structure.

---

An example, as requested:

```
if(Char.IsNumber(C))
{
  // Character is marked as a unicode number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if:

```
int ordinal = (int)C;
if(( ordinal >= 65 && ordinal <= 90 ) || (ordinal >= 48 && ordinal <= 57))
{
Console.WriteLine( C + " is an uppercase A-Z or 0-9!" );
}
```

Comment: Oded's answer is better because it uses built in constructs

Comment: Also, thank you for sharing that his answer may be better, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just use Char.IsNumber and Char.IsUpper methods:
see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s91f3by.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx

if (C.IsNumber || C.IsUpper)
{
 // password code!
}

(don't write your own password generator, unless it's just for fun though).

Comment: I am doing it for fun mostly; but why should I not, if it wasn't for fun?